# How to restrict IP addresses in web.config IIS 10 Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, iis, web-config

Windows Server 2016 IIS 10

I have this in web.config

```
<security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
        <clear />
        <add ipAddress="xx.xx.x.x" />
    </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

I have also set in ApplicationHost.config

```
section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow"
```

I have also installed the IP and Domain Restrictions Role for IIS

However, it STILL does not work.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is "it" that is not working?

Comment: To prove it really does not work, you have to use FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: I proved it doesn't work by adding my own IP and not being restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Once denied IP addresses have been added, click `Edit Feature Settings...` and select `Allow` for `Access for unspecified clients`. Click `OK`.

[image]

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: I will just add inbound rules to my EC2 security group.  That does work.

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can mark solution as answer.